# Python And Py2Exe: "%1 Is Not A Valid Win32 Application"

Tags: python, windows-7, py2exe

I'm trying to compile a python project into an executable. To test this, I've got Py2Exe installed, and am trying to do their Hello.py test. Here is hello.py:

```
print "Hello World!"
```

Here is my setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['hello.py'])
```

I do the following on the command line:

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

And I get it mostly working until it start 'finding dlls needed', at which point we get:

```
Traceback:
<some trace>
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Python version is 2.6.6, and I'm on a 32-bit machine running Windows 7. Any ideas or help most appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Py2Exe: DLL load failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782117/py2exe-dll-load-failed)

Comment: I've tried the suggested solutions; no dice unfortunately.

Comment: Try to find which DLL is missing thanks to a tool like http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Answer (score 1):

In my experience `py2exe` is rather difficult to use, a bit hit-and-miss in terms of whether it will work or not, and an absolute nightmare to get working at all with any `matplotlib` import.

I realise this question is quite old now, but I am not sure why people continue to use `py2exe` when there are much smoother functioning alternatives available.  I have have good results with `pyinstaller` (which was recommended to me after asking a question here on SO where I was also battling with `py2exe`).  Now every time I have tried it it "just worked", so if you're still interested in packing up python code into executables then try give this app a shot instead.

http://www.pyinstaller.org/

***Note:***  `py2exe` hasn't been updated for some years, while python and 3rd party modules have, which must be partly why it often doesn't work particularly well these days.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like step 5 in this tutorial describes what you are experiencing:

http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial#Step5

Comment: I've looked into it but as far as I can tell I have the redistributable installed on my machine. That means it should at least compile, even if it doesn't actually ship with the DLL. No?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, this is what I was able to do [Q-A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024386/py2exe-sqlite-not-a-valid-win-32-application/24039907#24039907).  Basically, I downloaded the updated sqlite dll file from sqlite.org.  I replaced the py2exe generated DLL file with this new file.  The program worked after that.  Do make sure you download the 32-bit DLL, however.