# DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application - Appcelerator

Tags: android, python, dll, appcelerator

When I try to run an app in Appcelerator (3.1.x) on the built-in Android emulator I'm getting a Python error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Donny\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.1.3.GA\android\fastdev.py", line 10, in <module>
    import urllib, threading
  File "C:\csvn\Python25\lib\urllib.py", line 26, in <module>
    import socket
  File "C:\csvn\Python25\lib\socket.py", line 47, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I'm not proficient in Python, but what I understand from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676433/solving-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-for-pygame), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782117/py2exe-dll-load-failed) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277875/dll-load-failed-1-is-not-valid-win32-application), is that I have a 32 bit version of Python trying to call a 64 bit DLL, right? I'm running on a 64 bit version of Windows 7, so this would make sense. If this is the case, how do I go about fixing this? Would I have to modify something in Appcelerator to use the 64 bit version of Python or possibly direct it to a 32 bit DLL instead?

Comment: This answer may help...

  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019720/importerror-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-but-the-dlls

Comment: Yes. I tried that. Thank you though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be using [this script](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/support/win32/findpython.bat) to locate your system's Python.  The script seems to be picking up a Python installation in `C:\csvn\Python25` which apparently comes with Collabnet's SVN for Windows and is in all likelihood not a full Python installation.

You should just install a standard 64-bit Python from python.org.  That little batch script seems to suggest they support Python 2.5 and 2.6, though 2.7 would likely work too.  Maybe to be on the safe side start with 2.6: http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6.6/

Just install to the normal default installation path of `C:\Python26` and make sure that path is early on your `%PATH%` environment variable.

Comment: This definitely pointed me in the right direction, but it didn't quite solve my problem.

Comment: Okay? What's the difficulty now then?

Comment: Wow. Never mind. That did the trick! I just tested it again and it's running. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I had that same issue with a different script.

I had both 32 and 64 bit python installed on my computer and when I just typed 'python' into it, it would run the 32 bit version.

I reinstalled my 64 bit version and then it picked that one when I just typed python.

Comment: Just putting the correct Python first on your `%PATH%` would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

this seems like a string format error.

i guess, code should be something like this ctype.WinDll('%1' % dllPath), but string not format as expected, so ctype treat '%1' like a dll path.

just guess.

Comment: Although that is in error and an annoyance it doesn't particularly have to do with the issue.