# Creating Executable File For Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, exe

I want to make an executable file from a python file the python file is written for Python 2.7.

I tried `pyinstaller` but it gives me an error when installing. I'm guessing it does not have support for Python 2.7 anymore.

Are there any alternatives for `pyinstaller` that work with Python 2.7?

I tried installing `cx_Freeze` version 5.1.1 but it gives me the following error:

```
Cleaning up...
Command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\win-10\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip_build_win-10\\cx-Freeze\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\win-10\appdata\local\temp\pip-cn4sd_-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in c:\users\win-10\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_win-10\cx-Freeze
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\win-10\pip\pip.log
```

when I install from wheel

```
cx_Freeze-5.1.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\win-10\pip\pip.log
```

**setup.py**

```py
from sys import executable
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(name='server', version='0.1', description='reverse shell server')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this problem some times ago, after a lot of googling I found the best solution for me.

### Alternatives

- [Py2Exe](https://www.py2exe.org/): Which is old, the last release on PyPi is on 21 October 2014.
- [pyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/): Is a nice tool, but with some problem that we will see later.
- [auto-py-to-exe](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/): Use pyInstaller to build the `.exe`, so suffer the same problem, but has a nice GUI and is intuitive to use.
- [cx_Freeze](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html): I think the best solution, because it was the only one that works in my case, it is also [recommended from python](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html)

### Investigation

During this time I looked on google and StackOverflow for the best solution, each time that I found something it was out-dated or not well explained/documented, so I studied the official docs.

#### py2exe

As first try I installed py2exe it seems the best option, also recommended from python, so, give it a try.
All goes fine during the installation process, so I decide to follow the [tutorial](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial) and get my `.exe`.

During the step 3 of the tutorial, running setup I received an error, looking on google I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782117/py2exe-dll-load-failed).

I gave up with py2exe.

#### auto-py-to-exe && pyInstaller

I have installed auto-py-to-exe and all went good, the program open without problems so I create my `.exe` file, that works!

The only problem was that, the program works only on my laptop, on all the other machine where I try to execute the antivirus delete it.

Looking on google I found the [github repository](https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe) where I found one [issue](https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe/issues/16) like the mine, reading it I understand that the problem is pyInstaller.

Looking on the [pyInstaller repository](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller) I found one [issue](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4633) where one contributors tells to contact the antivirus vendo, so I gave up again.

#### cx_Freeze

Looking the [docs](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html) it seems to be overcomplicated realize a simple `.exe`, so I have studied the documentation and found what I need. If you need support for Python 2.x, cx_Freeze version 5.1.x should be used instead, to do it just run `pip install cx-Freeze==5.1.1`

- Open you project folder and create inside it a `setup.py` file with inside:

  ```py
  import sys
  from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

  setup(  name = "myProgram",
          version = "0.1",
          description = "",
          executables = [Executable("myProgram.py")])
  ```

  Setting up this file require a little bit of study, there are multiple options to set. You can set the option to create a simple `.exe` or also the create a windows/mac/linux installer.
- Once you have your file ready, with the options that you need, just open a shell/terminal/cmd in the directory where the `setup.py` file is located and execute: `python setup.py build`
- Now in your project folder you will see a folder where inside you can find your `.exe` file.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221123/discussion-on-answer-by-carlo-zanocco-creating-executable-file-for-python-2-7).